# How to redirect to login screen in react navigation tab navigator with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I'm trying to figure out how to go about coding this.
I'm using a React Navigation TabNavigator as my main navigator and am also using Redux to manage my app and user's auth state.

One of the tabs has content that can only be displayed if the user is logged in so what I am trying to do is when they press that tab, if they are not logged in yet, I want to redirect to or pop a modal on top with a login/registration screen. 
After they have successfully logged in and their content pulled down, then I want to show the screen in the tab that they were originally trying to view.
So how would you go about this?

From my understanding with the TabNavigator, after the initial load then componentWillMount does not run each time I click on that tab so I can't check my auth state there and react.

Is there a way to intercept the tab press otherwise and be able to check my auth state from there before loading the view for that tab?

Comment: why not log user in before using the app / allowing them to go to that tab?

Comment: @Eduard I would prefer it that way too but the business requirements call for instant anonymous usage of certain functionality, with only advanced features being tied to an account.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to activate **lazy** options on TabNavigator config, eg:

```
const AppNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
    /* the screen needed auth */
    AddPost: {screen: AddPostScreen},
    ...
  },
  {
    lazy: true,
    ...
})
```

Second, I add this package [react-navigation-is-focused-hoc](https://github.com/pmachowski/react-navigation-is-focused-hoc)

`$ yarn add react-navigation-is-focused-hoc`

It's for the checking active screen, on react render AppNavigator add some props:

```
...
import { updateFocus } from 'react-navigation-is-focused-hoc';
...
return (
    ...
    <AppNavigator
      onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
        updateFocus(currentState);
      }}
    />
    ...
  );
```

The last, add **isFocused** to your Authenticated screen (AddPostScreen):

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation-is-focused-hoc';
...
@withNavigationFocus('AddPostScreen')
class AddPostScreen extends React.Component {
   static navigationOptions = () => ({
      /* Your navigation options */
   })

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { isFocused, auth: { signedIn }, navigation: { navigate } } = this.props;
    if (!isFocused && nextProps.isFocused && !signedIn) {
      navigate('LoginScreen');
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    const { isFocused } = this.props;
    if (isFocused && !nextProps.isFocused) {
      return true;
    }

    // Don't update if the screen is not focused
    if (!isFocused && !nextProps.isFocused) {
      return false;
    }

    // Update the screen if its re-enter
    return !isFocused && nextProps.isFocused;
  }

   render() {
      return (
       /* return authenticated component */
       ...
```

**signedIn** (boolean) is state from your auth reducers

Comment: Thanks for direction and great code example. I'll give it a try and see how it goes!